# How to automate combining audio and video files together

Tags: javascript, typescript, api

I wrote a simple bot that grabs the video and audio files from reddit (these files are always  seperated on reddit api) and now I am looking for an easy way to automate combining the audio and video files together using an npm or possibly FFmpeg or some other way.
I could use a video editor and combine the files that way one by one but I want to do it inside my program which will save me a lot of work.
Do any of you know of a npm that can easily do this? I searched myself but couldn't find anything.
I am programming in typescript. Both audio and video files come in mp4 format.

I have searched online for an npm that does this but only found a few that can combine multiple audio files together, none that combine a video and audio file.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can do the job? It's an npm wrapper for ffmpeg

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but after trying for an hour now I can't seem to get this to work to output a file.